# How to cd into my local git repo from an AppleScript?

Tags: git, macos, shell, github, applescript

I am running a Mac using OSX Yosemite v10.10.5.

I want to push my local git repo to my remote using AppleScript.

So the git code would be:

shell

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/my-project.git
git push -u origin master
```

But in order to run this from the terminal, first I need to `cd` into my local directory.

```
cd my-directory
```

So how would I do all this from an AppleScript? Or the JavaScript option in the Script Editor would also help.

Comment: Put everything in a bash script and then just run that bash script from AppleScript?

Comment: @PaulR: That's a great idea! I would happily upvote and accept your answer if you could hint at how to run a bash script from AppleScript. At this point, I only know how to run individual shell commands from AppleScript.

Comment: You can just use `do shell script "my_script.sh"`. I would write up an answer but I'm on a mobile device just now - feel free to convert this to an answer if you like,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "git -C dir command" form to explicitly tell git where to work.

Answer (score 1):

Summary from comments (per @PaulR):

> Put everything in a bash script and then just run that bash script from AppleScript.

myAppleScript.applescript

```
do shell script "my_script.sh"
```